# Elasticsearch sort term aggregation by sum total of 2 nested term aggregations

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index which stores all the books and articles read by users.
The books and articles are of nested type.
I am trying to get the top x users who read the highest number of books and articles which match the specified genre filters.

I was able to get the total number of books read for each user (see aggregation below named books_total_reads)

I was also able to get the total number of articles read by each user (see aggregation below named articles_total_reads)

What i can't figure out is how to **sort** the the top x users by highest sum of: books_total_reads + articles_total_reads.

So in the example below, the query should return top 2 users in following order:
john (total 23)
alice (total 19)

To reproduce this you can run commands below:

```
PUT my-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "books": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "genre": { "type": "keyword"},
          "count": { "type": "integer" }
        }
      },
      "articles": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "genre": { "type": "keyword"},
          "count": { "type": "integer" }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT my-index/_doc/1
{
  "user" : "mark",
  "books" : [
    {
      "genre" : "1",
      "count" :  3
    },
    {
      "genre" : "2",
      "count" :  5
    }
  ],
  "articles" : [
    {
      "genre" : "10",
      "count" :  5
    },
    {
      "genre" : "11",
      "count" :  5
    }
  ]
}

PUT my-index/_doc/2
{
  "user" : "john",
  "books" : [
    {
      "genre" : "1",
      "count" :  1
    }
  ],
  "articles" : [
    {
      "genre" : "10",
      "count" :  2
    },
    {
      "genre" : "12",
      "count" :  20
    }
  ]
}

PUT my-index/_doc/3
{
  "user" : "alice",
  "books" : [
    {
      "genre" : "1",
      "count" :  4
    },
    {
      "genre" : "2",
      "count" :  5
    }
  ],
  "articles" : [
    {
      "genre" : "10",
      "count" :  5
    },
    {
      "genre" : "11",
      "count" :  5
    }
  ]
}


POST /my-index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "books",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "books.genre": [
                        "1",
                        "2"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "articles.genre": [
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "books_root_agg": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "books"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "books": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "books.genre",
                "include": [
                  "1",
                  "2"
                ],
                "size": 10,
                "order": {
                  "sum_reads": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "sum_reads": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "books.count"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "books_total_reads": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "books>sum_reads"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "articles_root_agg": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "articles": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "articles.genre",
                "include": [
                  "10",
                  "11",
                  "12"
                ],
                "size": 10,
                "order": {
                  "sum_reads": "desc"
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "sum_reads": {
                  "sum": {
                    "field": "articles.count"
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "articles_total_reads": {
              "sum_bucket": {
                "buckets_path": "articles>sum_reads"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Answer #1

You've done a great job. All you have to do is sum the results and sort the baskets. I removed terms aggregations because you already filter with the bool query. The sum_bucket aggregation is redundant

```
POST /my-index/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "books",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "books.genre": [
                        "1",
                        "2"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "articles.genre": [
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "size": 2
      },
      "aggs": {
        "book_total_reads": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "books"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_reads": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "books.count"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "article_total_reads": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "articles"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_reads": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "articles.count"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        "total_reads": {
          "bucket_script": {
            "buckets_path": {
              "books_read": "book_total_reads.sum_reads",
              "article_read": "article_total_reads.sum_reads"
            },
            "script": "params.books_read + params.article_read"
          }
        },
        "sort_total_reads": {
          "bucket_sort": {
            "sort": [
              {
                "total_reads": "desc"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answer #2

Your conceptual problem is dividing the entire READ entity into two: BOOK_READ and ARTICLE_READ, which is why your query and my query (see answer #1) are so bulky. What will you do with your mapping, documents and queries if you have a new type of publication - comics?

Normalizing data with new mapping

```
PUT my-index-normalized
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "user": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "publication": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "genre": {"type": "keyword"},
          "type":  {"type": "keyword"},
          "count": {"type": "integer"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Сreating documents using the bulk request

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"my-index-normalized","_id":"1"}}
{"user":"mark","publication":[{"genre":"1","type":"book","count":3},{"genre":"2","type":"book","count":5},{"genre":"10","type":"article","count":5},{"genre":"11","type":"article","count":5}]}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index-normalized","_id":"2"}}
{"user":"john","publication":[{"genre":"1","type":"book","count":1},{"genre":"10","type":"article","count":2},{"genre":"12","type":"article","count":20}]}
{"index":{"_index":"my-index-normalized","_id":"3"}}
{"user":"alice","publication":[{"genre":"1","type":"book","count":4},{"genre":"2","type":"book","count":5},{"genre":"10","type":"article","count":5},{"genre":"11","type":"article","count":5}]}
```

Updated query for normalized data

```
POST /my-index-normalized/_search?filter_path=aggregations
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "publication",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "publication.type": {
                        "value": "book"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "publication.genre": [
                        "1",
                        "2"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            },
            {
              "bool": {
                "filter": [
                  {
                    "term": {
                      "publication.type": {
                        "value": "article"
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "terms": {
                      "publication.genre": [
                        "10",
                        "11",
                        "12"
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "users": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "user",
        "size": 2,
        "order": {
          "total_reads>sum_reads": "desc"
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "total_reads": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "publication"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "sum_reads": {
              "sum": {
                "field": "publication.count"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Update 2024/02/16

Dear @Assaf you can  change the existing mapping to combine subentities into one by reindexing

Reindex query with a script

```
POST _reindex
{
    "source": {
        "index": "my-index"
    },
    "dest": {
        "index": "my-index-normalized"
    },
    "script": {
        "source": """
                List toPublications(def oldPublications,
                def publicationType, def publicationTypeFieldName) {
                    def publications = new LinkedList();
                    for (oldPublication in oldPublications) {
                        def publication = oldPublication;
                        publication.put(publicationTypeFieldName, publicationType);
                        publications.add(publication);
                    }
                    return publications;
                }
                def publications;
                def allPublications = new LinkedList();
                
                def books = ctx._source.books;
                publications = toPublications(books, "book", params.publication_type_field_name);
                allPublications.addAll(publications);
                ctx._source.remove('books');
                
                def articles = ctx._source.articles;
                publications = toPublications(articles, "article", params.publication_type_field_name);
                allPublications.addAll(publications);
                ctx._source.remove('articles');
                
                ctx._source[params.new_field_name] = allPublications;
        """,
        "params": {
            "new_field_name": "publications",
            "publication_type_field_name": "type"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, for the suggested mapping above. I understand this approach is better because it leaves room for supporting additional publication types in the future... however, we do not expect additional publication types in the near future and we cannot change the existing mapping .
Therefore your previous answer  #1 is my preferred solution.

Comment: @Assaf, your first argument "we do not expect additional publication types in the near future" isn’t acceptable. When designing software systems, it is necessary to take into account their possible extension